target version error while installing nuget package to uwp solution
I'm trying to add WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed package to my uwp solution and I receive error
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details Error Could not install package 'WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed 0.1.7.9'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'native,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package autho
my target platform version is 10.0.20348.0 and target platform min version is 10.0.17763.0
Visual Studio 2022 v143
I cannot understand why it shows my target version as v0.0.
NOTE: this solution is an uwp build export of a unity project.

It is recommended that you install "WindowsAzure.Messaging.Managed" in a blank UWP project to see if it can be installed successfully.

It also shows the same error trying to install package on a blank project.
